# Angular UI datepicker overrides placeholder text

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'd like to have custom placeholder text on the input field of my datepicker. Currently my placeholder text gets overridden by 'MM/DD/YYYY'

Here's my html:

```html
<input type="text" id=" coverpagedatefrom" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-valid-date" data-ng-model="publishCtrl.clipbookSvc.clipbookModel.coverPageDateFrom" data-uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" data-ng-focus="publishCtrl.open($event, 'date1')" data-is-open="publishCtrl.datepickers.date1" data-datepicker-options="publishCtrl.dateOptions" placeholder="Enter Date">
```

Here's what gets outputed to the dom:

```html
<input type="text" id=" coverpagedatefrom" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-valid-date" data-ng-model="publishCtrl.clipbookSvc.clipbookModel.coverPageDateFrom" data-uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" data-ng-focus="publishCtrl.open($event, 'date1')" data-is-open="publishCtrl.datepickers.date1" data-datepicker-options="publishCtrl.dateOptions" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
```

How can I prevent the Angular UI datepicker from changing the placeholder text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem...

I tried it:

```
<input type="{{rbDtValue ? 'date' : 'text'}}" 
                id="{{id}}" 
                class="{{clazz}}" 
                onfocus="this.type='date';" 
                onblur="javascript: if( !this.value ) this.type='text';"
                placeholder="{{placeholder | i18n}}"

                uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy"
                ng-model="rbDtValue"/>
```

When rbDtValue is not null, the type of the input was changed, but when I select a value in the popup, this value is not set on the input, and it shows just the mask.

If I donn't change the input type, the value is set normally.

#### Update

### Solution 01: using element events

I find a solution, based on this example: http://jsfiddle.net/U2Ft5/4/

First a create the follow css classes:

```
.rb-date-picker {
    width: 150px!important;
    display: inline-block;
}

.rb-date-picker.placeholder::before{
    width:100%;
    color: #888888;
    content:attr(placeholder);
}
```

Then, I create this element:

```
<input type="date" 
                id="{{id}}" 
                class="input-large text-field-gra rb-date-picker " 
                ng-class="{ 'placeholder': !rbDtValue}"
                onfocus="javascript: $( this ).removeClass('placeholder');" 
                onblur="javascript: if( !this.value ) $( this ).addClass('placeholder');"
                placeholder="{{placeholder | i18n}}"
                uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy"

                ng-model="rbDtValue"/>
```

The behavior is:

1).rb-date-picker.placeholder::before{...}: this simulate the placeholder. It's important to use "width: 100%"

2) ng-class="{ 'placeholder': !rbDtValue}": its apply the placeholder class when the value is null

3) onfocus: remove the placeholder class

4) onblur: put the placeholder class case the value is null

### Solution 02: using css

In addition to classes created for first solution, I create the follow class:

```
.rb-date-picker.placeholder:focus::before{
    width:0%;
    content:"";
}
```

And remove the javascript events, and the element is like this:

```
<input type="date" 
                id="{{id}}" 
                class="input-large text-field-gra rb-date-picker " 
                ng-class="{ 'placeholder': !rbDtValue}"
                placeholder="{{placeholder | i18n}}"
                uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy"

                ng-model="rbDtValue"/>
```

It's simpler than the first, but both working for me on the google chrome.

Comment: Thank you, very usefull answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

On angular-bootstap#0.14.3 it seems to work by just setting `placeholder="{{::vm.placeholder}}"`

Answer (score 0):

The most simple workaround is to just have an ng-change function that would be called to initialize the ng-model. Thats it.

```
<input class="date-icon form-control" type="text" name="eed" id="" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" ng-click="vm.openTo($event)" class="date-icon date-input" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="vm.program.end_date" is-open="vm.isToOpened" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="vm.dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" required ng-change="bindDateTo()" max="vm.maxStartDate"/>
```